# I tried to connect frontend and backend but I got this error CORS policy:

Tags: javascript, proxy, cors

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://nms.urinboydev.uz/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

the data had to come from the backend

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

You basically need to add a header of

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <the origin you are to allow>
```

to the backend, which will let your browser know that the server allows this operation. Of course, in the placeholder above you can put whatever URL you want, or `*` if you want to allow it for every possible source.